# Swift Socket IO: Event Handler not called

Tags: ios, swift3, socket.io

I m working with SocketIO and everything working fines like connection, send data from iOS to Android but when android send data to iOS device that time socket io event handler method not called. I have seen the below logs but method not called.

```
LOG SocketEngine: Writing poll:  has data: false
LOG SocketEnginePolling: Sending poll:  as type: 2
LOG SocketEnginePolling: Created POST string: 1:2
LOG SocketEnginePolling: POSTing
LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling request
LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got polling response
LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling request
LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 3
```

Code Snippet:

```
socket.connect()
socket.on("connect") {data, ack in
    if Id > 0 {
        SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.connectToServerWithId(String(Id), completionHandler: {
            (userList) -> Void in
        })
    }
}
socket.on("result") { (dataArray, socketAck) -> Void in
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "receivedResultNotification"), object: dataArray[0] as! [String: AnyObject])
}
```

Any help that would great for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like:

```
socket.on("connect") {
   [weak self] data, ack in
}
```